# Spring Cucumber Set Application Properties for Beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cucumber, cucumber-java

I Have a bean defined in a configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
  @Value("${some-property}")
  private String someProperty;

  @Bean
  public SomeBean someBean() {
    return new SomeBean(someProperty);
  }
}
```

How do I define a cucumber step definition to set the property `some-property` and let `SomeBean` to use it?

The problem I'm facing is that my beans are initialized before any steps happen. How do I reinitialize a bean, or refresh using the `@RefreshScope` maybe? Or can I start/restart the spring context in a later step?

Cucumber step:

```
@Given("I have some property set to (.*)")
public void someProperty(String someProperty) {
  // Answer
}
```

And here's the empty step definition class to start Spring Context:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("it")
@AutoConfigureCache
@AutoConfigureTestEntityManager
@AutoConfigureWebMvc
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(secure = false)
@ImportAutoConfiguration
public class CucumberSpringContextBootstrapper implements En {
}
```